# Tidyeval: pass list of columns as quosure to select()

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, nse, tidyeval

I want to pass a bunch of columns to `pmap()` inside `mutate()`. Later, I want to select those same columns.

At the moment, I'm passing a list of column names to `pmap()` as a quosure, which works fine, although I have no idea whether this is the "right" way to do it. But I can't figure out how to use the same quosure/list for `select()`.

I've got almost no experience with tidyeval, I've only got this far by playing around. I imagine there must be a way to use the same thing both for `pmap()` and `select()`, preferably without having to put each of my column names in quotation marks, but I haven't found it yet.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(a = 1:3,
             b = 101:103) %>% 
    print
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1   101
#> 2     2   102
#> 3     3   103

cols_quo <- quo(list(a, b))

df2 <- df %>% 
    mutate(outcome = !!cols_quo %>% 
               pmap_int(function(..., word) {
                   args <- list(...)

                   # just to be clear this isn't what I actually want to do inside pmap
                   return(args[[1]] + args[[2]])
               })) %>% 
    print()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a     b outcome
#>   <int> <int>   <int>
#> 1     1   101     102
#> 2     2   102     104
#> 3     3   103     106

# I get why this doesn't work, but I don't know how to do something like this that does
df2 %>% 
    select(!!cols_quo)
#> Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...): object 'a' not found
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bit tricky because of the mix of semantics involved in this problem. `pmap()` takes a list and passes each element as its own argument to a function (it's kind of equivalent to `!!!` in that sense). Your quoting function thus needs to quote its arguments and somehow pass a list of columns to `pmap()`.

Our quoting function can go one of two ways. Either quote (i.e., delay) the list creation, or create an actual list of quoted expressions right away:

```
quoting_fn1 <- function(...) {
  exprs <- enquos(...)

  # For illustration purposes, return the quoted inputs instead of
  # doing something with them. Normally you'd call `mutate()` here:
  exprs
}

quoting_fn2 <- function(...) {
  expr <- quo(list(!!!enquos(...)))

  expr
}
```

Since our first variant does nothing but return a list of quoted inputs, it's actually equivalent to `quos()`:

```
quoting_fn1(a, b)
#> <list_of<quosure>>
#>
#> [[1]]
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^a
#> env:  global
#>
#> [[2]]
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^b
#> env:  global
```

The second version returns a quoted expression that instructs R to create a list with quoted inputs:

```
quoting_fn2(a, b)
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^list(^a, ^b)
#> env:  0x7fdb69d9bd20
```

There is a subtle but important difference between the two. The first version creates an actual list object:

```
exprs <- quoting_fn1(a, b)
typeof(exprs)
#> [1] "list"
```

On the other hand, the second version does not return a list, it returns an expression for creating a list:

```
expr <- quoting_fn2(a, b)
typeof(expr)
#> [1] "language"
```

Let's find out which version is more appropriate for interfacing with `pmap()`. But first we'll give a name to the pmapped function to make the code clearer and easier to experiment with:

```
myfunction <- function(..., word) {
  args <- list(...)
  # just to be clear this isn't what I actually want to do inside pmap
  args[[1]] + args[[2]]
}
```

Understanding how tidy eval works is hard in part because we usually don't get to observe the unquoting step. We'll use `rlang::qq_show()` to reveal the result of unquoting `expr` (the delayed list) and `exprs` (the actual list) with `!!`:

```
rlang::qq_show(
  mutate(df, outcome = pmap_int(!!expr, myfunction))
)
#> mutate(df, outcome = pmap_int(^list(^a, ^b), myfunction))

rlang::qq_show(
  mutate(df, outcome = pmap_int(!!exprs, myfunction))
)
#> mutate(df, outcome = pmap_int(<S3: quosures>, myfunction))
```

When we unquote the delayed list, `mutate()` calls `pmap_int()` with `list(a, b)`, evaluated in the data frame, which is exactly what we need:

```
mutate(df, outcome = pmap_int(!!expr, myfunction))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a     b outcome
#>   <int> <int>   <int>
#> 1     1   101     102
#> 2     2   102     104
#> 3     3   103     106
```

On the other hand, if we unquote an actual list of quoted expressions, we get an error:

```
mutate(df, outcome = pmap_int(!!exprs, myfunction))
#> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
#>   Evaluation error: Element 1 is not a vector (language).
```

That's because the quoted expressions inside the list are not evaluated in the data frame. In fact, they are not evaluated at all. `pmap()` gets the quoted expressions as is, which it doesn't understand. Recall what `qq_show()` has shown us:

```
#> mutate(df, outcome = pmap_int(<S3: quosures>, myfunction))
```

Anything inside angular brackets is passed as is. This is a sign that we should somehow have used `!!!` instead, to inline each element of the list of quosures in the surrounding expression. Let's try it:

```
rlang::qq_show(
  mutate(df, outcome = pmap_int(!!!exprs, myfunction))
)
#> mutate(df, outcome = pmap_int(^a, ^b, myfunction))
```

Hmm... Doesn't look right. We're supposed to pass a list to `pmap_int()`, and here it gets each quoted input as separate argument. Indeed we get a type error:

```
mutate(df, outcome = pmap_int(!!!exprs, myfunction))
#> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
#>   Evaluation error: `.x` is not a list (integer).
```

That's easy to fix, just splice into a call to `list()`:

```
rlang::qq_show(
  mutate(df, outcome = pmap_int(list(!!!exprs), myfunction))
)
#> mutate(df, outcome = pmap_int(list(^a, ^b), myfunction))
```

And voilà!

```
mutate(df, outcome = pmap_int(list(!!!exprs), myfunction))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a     b outcome
#>   <int> <int>   <int>
#> 1     1   101     102
#> 2     2   102     104
#> 3     3   103     106
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `quos` when there are more than one element and evaluate with `!!!`

```
cols_quo <- quos(a, b)
df2 %>%
    select(!!!cols_quo)
```

The object 'df2' can be created with

```
df %>%
    mutate(output = list(!!! cols_quo) %>% 
        reduce(`+`))
```

---

If we want to use the quosure as in the OP's post

```
cols_quo <- quo(list(a, b))
df2 %>%
    select(!!! as.list(quo_expr(cols_quo))[-1])
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      a     b
#  <int> <int>
#1     1   101
#2     2   102
#3     3   103
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that too and it does work in the select step, but how do I make that work in the intermediate step with pmap?